# What happened to Mohini?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, urdu-language, premchand

In Premchand's short story "The Desired Destination" (first published in 1911, [available here in its original Urdu](https://www.rekhta.org/stories/manzil-e-maqsood-premchand-stories)), the narrator is in love with a girl named Mohini and opens by saying that she "is no more". The story relates how she gets in a boat in the dead of night to chase a bobbing lantern down a raging river, although it doesn't say how they get back to safety after this dangerous adventure, and how she becomes melancholy and sorrowful after this incident. The story ends with her commentary on a funeral pyre.

What does it mean that Mohini "is no more"? Did she die, and if so, how, and why isn't that part of the story? Or does it just refer to her strange loss of spirit after seeing the lantern go out? The story feels ... odd to me, and it feels like I'm missing a lot of subtext or implications, or maybe symbolism or allegory.